# Set 2 SelectMode in Fancytree

Tags: javascript, fancytree

I use fancytree and want to use 2 selectMode in 1 tree source. Can I do it?

The part 1 is SelectMode:2 and I want part 2 is SelectMode:3
What should I do everyone?

Here is an example of what I want to do...

[image: example-what I want to]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Comment: thanks Momin. I use example code: http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/sample-ext-persist.html#

Answer (score 0):

A mix of selectMode 2 and 3 is not supported out of the box.
You could however use selectMode 2 and implement the selection propagation yourself in the `select` or `click` events.
Have a look at the [fixSelection3AfterClick](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/doc/jsdoc/FancytreeNode.html#fixSelection3AfterClick) method.